# Copy textbox value to another - ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following form within an ASP.NET MVC 5 application

```
@model ProjectOasis.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    //more form stuff
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

How do I make it so that whenever a value is entered into the m.Email textbox that the value is immediately copied into the m.UserName textbox? (I will be making the UserName textbox un-editable after I have this working).

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to do this through Javascript.

Comment: As Dimitar mentioned you need to do this with javascript/jquery, but whats the point - just copy the value server side when you post the form

Comment: Because I specifically want the user to see that their login name = email address.

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to just display the username, here is an example (vanilla js), something like:

```js
document.getElementById("txt2").onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.value;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" disabled />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

or here is the jquery version:

```js
$("#txt2").on("keyup", function() { 
  $("#txt1").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" disabled />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do I put this into a Razor view engine example as displayed above?

Comment: @mansonitefirefox Well you'd include it in your Scripts bundle (perhaps in a separate `.js` file). I'm afraid this might get a bit broad if you don't know how to include javascript in your views ... I can write about it maybe (when I have some free time).

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript. Probably you have already included jQuery in your site scripts. So, all you have to do is to add following script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#Email").change(function(){
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Please ensure about letter casing since I am not sure if Razor camelifies names or not - just preview HTML source in your browser and check the field names spelling.

Here is [some working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3mge6yLc/) for you

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
 $("#Email").change(function(){
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val());
 });
```

**Option 2**

```
 $("#Email").focusout(function(){
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val());
 });
```

and to enforce to use email as username, have this in your username textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" }
```